# i used new operator but it occurs error

Tags: debugging, new-operator

Unhandled exception at 0x5F0C08AB (msvcr120d.dll) in ConsoleApplication10.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000003E7.

It's weird.
I just made new memory.
code is too long to show you guys.
I debug it and it breaks where the line i used new operator.

Comment: Please post the code that calls the new operator.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the problem was in other line which is for loop. Index number was the problem. but why didn't the debugger  point that line ? is it kind of bug? Furthermore, if index number bigger than array length, it doesn't stop and keep going. why is that? I'm confused.

Comment: If index number is greater than the array length , it copies garbage value.

Comment: You didn't state what language you're using but in C++ and C it's indeed possible to access elements outside the array bounds. It could crash the program or produce garbage values.

Comment: I'm using C++. Thanks for the answer. is there the way to make compiler stop when it access  elements outside the array bounds?

Comment: When compiling, some array bugs can be found using a higher warning level. Static analysis tools like CppCheck can also help. When running the program, you can use tools like Valgrind or enabling more runtime debug options in Visual Studio's settings. Also compiling a Debug build instead of Release enables some error detection.

Comment: OH thank you! your answer helped a lot :)